# I am not getting log.error() in log4j, how to get it?

Tags: java, log4j

I am new to this Log4j.jar, i am trying to add exception in the log but i am not getting the `error()` method in the logger.

Can anyone help me with this. I am new.

Steps which I did:
 **1.** Created eclipse java project 
 **2.** Added Log4j-1.2.17.jar file in the project

Now i am trying to add the error it is not coming.

My code is

```
package log;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestFile1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestFile1.class.getName());
    log.info("This is my first logger message");
    log.warning("This is warning");
    System.out.println("Hello");
    int a = 2;
    int b = 0;
    try {
        int c = a/b;    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

In catch exception, I am not getting the error method when I try `log.error()`

Answer (score 0):

Java.util.Logger is not the LOGGER of Log4j. You should use the import org.apache.log4j for it.

Comment: yes i changed that and tried i got it but now when i run it i am getting following error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Do you have a log4j.properties file ?